# Python to Automate Fusion 360 with COM

Tags: python, api, win32com, autodesk, fusion360

I've searched everywhere for a solution to this problem but I haven't found it yet. 
I know that Autodesk Inventor can be automated with Python using win32com package by:

win32com.client.Dispatch("Inventor.Application")

However I can't find the "prodID" that is needed to use this package with Fusion 360 and no documentation for automation ever being done this way with this package.
I need to be able to control a range of other processes so it would be ideal if I could use Python to launch Fusion 360 and perform operations without having to load the script within the application itself. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fusion 360 API is not a COM API so it's not possible to use win32com to drive it.   To use the API, your program must be either an add-in or script running from within Fusion 360.